# Spacing going crazy

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent the paragraphs to spread out over the page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33977/how-to-prevent-the-paragraphs-to-spread-out-over-the-page)

When I try to put some tables in my document I get lots of white space between the section (which I am guessing its because latex is trying to adjust positioning of the tables). Sometimes I get tables appearing on a single page by themselves. Is there a way to avoid this? Below is an image of a page showing the ugly spacing. (The boxes represent text areas)[image]

Comment: Do you use `flushbottom`?

Comment: Nope I only use center

Comment: Have a look at [How to prevent the paragraphs to spread out over the page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33977/how-to-prevent-the-paragraphs-to-spread-out-over-the-page).

Comment: What is on the page exactly following the one you're showing? If it's a table (or some other unbreakable structure) that is *not floating*, then that might cause the problem.

Comment: It's a paragraph of text

Comment: I used \raggedbottom in the preamble as shown on the page suggested by @StefanKottwitz and it seems to be fixed! Thanks!