# Prevent vertical distribution of paragraphs over entire page

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, paragraphs

It seems it tries to fill an entire A4, as the image of the next page is too big. So it puts a lot of space between the paragraphs. But, I'd much rather have a big chunk of white at the bottom of the first page: as it looks now, it looks like there are stuff missing (for example figures).

Comment: Use `\clearpage` before `\begin{figure}`

Comment: Simple as that.

Comment: And don't use the `[H]` specifier provided by `float`.

Comment: You might look for `\raggedbottom` (cf. [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33977/14697), possible duplicate).

Comment: @egrep: I'm not following?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on your given information I guess you are using a document class like `book`. By default the command `\flushbottom` is active which will balance the complete text at the top and bottom of a page.

If you get a page break the text before will be balanced. A simple `\clearpage` before you start the environment `figure` will solve the problem.

The behaviour can be reproduced very simple if you are using the float specifier `H` provided by the package `float`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\chapter{foo}
\blindtext

\blindtext

\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{example-image-a}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{MWE to demonstrate how to place to images side-by-side}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

So I recommend to use the specifiers `!htb`. More information about the float algorithm and the specifiers are given in the great answer of Frank Mittelbach:

[How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat)

Comment: I am using `\report` and yes, `\clearpage` did it.