# Unwanted Line Breaks between Paragraphs

Tags: formatting

I am typing up an article in LaTeX and everything works perfectly, but for some reason there is a point where there are a few paragraphs where there is a line break between each paragraph.  Has anyone had this problem before or knows how to deal with it?  I am simply typing out a line as follows

like this

then the next paragraph

Rather than moving down to the next line for the next paragraph as it does for most of the article, it instead skips a line.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you please include a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the issue you describe?

Comment: @ leandriis That's the thing, I don't even know how someone would reproduce it.  The document is fine and then for no reason there are a few paragraphs with line breaks.

Comment: Copy your original document, comment out some lines of the content, compile and see if the problem stays. If so, repeat until you have the smallest possible document that still reproduces the issue. Include this document into your question.

Comment: most likely you have a document with `\flushbottom` in effect and at the start of the next page there is a large unbreakable item that will not fit on this page. But we can only guess if you show no example

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36423/random-unwanted-space-between-paragraphs/36429#36429  or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33977/how-to-prevent-the-paragraphs-to-spread-out-over-the-page/33981#33981  or ...

Comment: @David Carlisle One of the answers to the first question had a quick solution which worked, thanks a lot.  It was because I didn't have anything in the code to allow the height of each column to vary from page to page.