# how to remove unwanted space between pages

Tags: spacing

I am writing a thesis in LaTeX with predefined styles which works fine. However, sometimes, when I finish a sub-section and start writing the new sub-section, LaTeX automatically stretches the text and adds more space (between paragraphs) in order to put the new title on the next page. Once I use `\clearpage` at the end of the current sub-section, it removes the spaces in between and makes it fine, but again starts the new part in the next page while there is still some space left at the last page before the new sub-section.

Comment: Add  `\raggedbottom` to your preamble (the default is `\flushbottom`), or use the `bottomtitles` option of the  `titlesec` package.

Comment: See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10743/why-does-latex-stretch-small-sections-across-the-whole-page-vertically