# How to fix the inconsistent paragraph spaces in this MWE using KOMA?

Tags: vertical-alignment, koma-script, libertine

**MWE code**

```
\documentclass[twoside=semi, a4paper, 11pt, open=any, chapterprefix=false, toc=graduated]{scrbook} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{libertine} %uncomment
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath} %uncomment 
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter One}
\blindtext[3]

\blindtext[1]
\section{Section One}
\blindtext[2]

\blindtext[3]
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\blindtext[4]

\blindtext[3]
\end{document}
```

**Output -- unwanted spaces**
[image]

**Output -- desired effect**

[image]

**Question**
How to fix this inconsistency in the same document? I noticed that by uncommenting the `libertine` lines of code the problem disappears.

**Note**
- compilation with XeLaTeX
`This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99991 (TeX Live 2014/W32TeX) (preloaded format=xelatex 2014.9.2)`

Comment: This has nothing to to with KOMAscript or the libertine-package. The option twoside use \flushbottom as default, and the the spacing between paragraphs is stretched to flush the bottom of the pages. Add \raggedbottom to the preamble and the uneven spacing disappear.

Comment: As Sveinung says. Basically a duplicate of [Why does latex stretch small sections across the whole page vertically?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10743) I suppose?