# Stop elements from being pulled apart one page

Tags: spacing, page-breaking

I have a very long LaTeX document with many tables, figures, etc. 
When I have a long table on the following site (which means it doesn't fit on the current site) the elements (paragraphs, tables, figures...) on the current site are pulled apart, so that the first element is at the top of the page and last one at the bottom,with large white spaces inbetween each element.

Is it possible to change this, so that in such a case the elements would be as normal at the top with just aone large white space at the bottom of the page?

Comment: This is to get a nice clean margin at the bottom. You can use `\raggedbottom`.

Comment: Related: [Why does latex stretch small sections across the whole page vertically?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10743)