# New line, line breaking, `\\`: a definitive answer

Tags: line-breaking

In most basic courses of latex, they say that to separate two block of texts, you need to use `\\` at the end of the first one. Anyway, this seems to be a bad practice according to lot of people (see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235752/new-line-size-what-can-i-do) for example).

Actually, I have:

- guides and tutorial that say how to use `\\` caring about nothing
- people around that say "don't use this please!", but often no motivation is given.

I would like to have a good and definitive answer, hoping that this could help also other users.

When am I meant to use `\\`?

What are the problems using `\\`?

Why does `\\` exist even if it is discouraged and leads to problems?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Those basic courses are telling a lie. Paragraphs should *always* be separated by a blank line.

Comment: Is simple:  Use \\  where you want a new line (`\newline`) . Do not use \\ where you want a  paragraph (`\par`). Use a blank line where you want a `\par`.   Do not confuse a `\newline` with a `\par`. Sometimes they seem to do the same,  but it is not true. For instance, compare both with or without `\parskip3em` in the preamble.

Comment: where are these "tutorials" can they be corrected?

Comment: In addition to @Fran 's comment: you should never* want a new line in ordinary body text, and you should very rarely want one at all outside of `tabular`/`array` environments and similar. [* Not ever for all practical purposes. Incredibly seldom. So rarely that you could spend years using LaTeX and never find yourself with such a desire.]

Comment: ok, maybe I got it. But what if I want a blank line between two pieces of text without having a lot of troubles?