# Proper way of line breaking

Tags: line-breaking

I know 2 options to break the line.

Option 1:

```
Abcdef\\
Ghijkl
```

Result:

```
Abcdef
Ghijkl
```

Option 2:

```
Abcdef

Ghijkl
```

Result:

```
Abcdef
  Ghijkl
```

Are there any rules when to use which?

PS: I'm using `scrreprt` as my document class.

Comment: There's also `\newline` and `\linebreak` by the way. See [What is the difference between \newline and \\?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27028/4778) and also this page: [Line breaks and blank spaces](https://it.sharelatex.com/learn/Line_breaks_and_blank_spaces) and the related [Reference guide](https://it.sharelatex.com/learn/Line_breaks_and_blank_spaces#Reference_guide)

Comment: Short answer: never use Option 1 in the regular body of your document. Use it to end the row in a tabular or align environment, for example, but not to start a new line in the main text.

Comment: \\ fills the rest of the current line with white space, so LaTeX cannot fit anything else there. An blank line in your source tells LaTeX to start a new paragraph.

Comment: For option 2, you should add `\noindent` \ unless you do want some indentation.

Comment: This is surely a duplicate? @Bernard Usually, you shouldn't need to. If you are doing that at all often, there is something wrong with your mark up. (There is often something wrong with mine, but that just confirms the point. :()

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82664/when-to-use-par-and-when, comments on http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240938/new-line-line-breaking-a-definitive-answer?rq=1.

Comment: @cfr: I (almost) never do that. But the O.P. might want to insert a blank line for readibility of the source-code. I think I didn't get exactly what the question was. Btw, the O.P. forgot to mention `\endgraf`. Under some some circumstances, it works, while a blank and \\  generate a complaint from the compiler.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks. No. I think maybe ***I*** didn't get what the question was. I didn't realise this was about source code....

Comment: Write `\parindent0pt\parskip0pt`  before and you will see the same effect in both cases. Then try  with  `\parindent1em\parskip1em` and you will understand why is not the same use a line  break that a new paragraph.

Comment: @cfr So what would you use in the main body? `\newline` or `\linebreak`?

Comment: @Alenanno Neither. I'd leave a blank line. If I want additional space before the next paragraph, I use something like `\smallskip` or, if really necessary, `\vskip`. But I wouldn't use those when writing something like a paper - only for something like teaching materials or a handout.

Comment: @Fran They are still not equivalent, though. Even in that case.

Comment: @cfr Oh interesting.

Comment: @cfr Of course, I did not tried to show that \\ and \par could be equivalent, on the contrary, that under certain conditions \par  could look  like a linebreak  but really  have a very different purpose.