# Unwanted spacing when inserting figure

Tags: spacing

I have a problem - when I insert figures in my document, latex creates a huge space between sections and text.

[image]

Any idea of how I change this? I may have code something in my main that went wrong, but I don't know what I am looking for in the main declaration..

My code for inserting the figure:
[image]

Comment: Probably same thing as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10743/why-does-latex-stretch-small-sections-across-the-whole-page-vertically/10747#10747

Comment: Without [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) we can only speculate. My speculation is, that you do not allow the figure to float but have a two-side document using a class that automatically uses `\flushbottom`. So either allow the figures to float or use explicte `\raggedbottom`. And please always add a MWE to your questions.

Comment: not really related to the figure, (unless you used `[H]`) just that you have specified flush bottom and that is the only way to achieve that in this case (apparently) we have to guess as you have shown no code.

Comment: Just let me know, what you need to see. My code for inserting figures is in the question. I can post my code for the main as well if needed?

Comment: Please do not show a screenshot of a code snippet. Add a MWE (see the link in my first comment)! Nevertheless: That's a exactly what David and I have speculated in our comments above. With `[H]` you don't allow the `figure` to float. And that's the main reason for your trouble. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370627/why-should-the-h-option-not-be-used-in-floats

Comment: So sorry, but I don't know how to create a MWE, the link you send do no tells anything about creating it, but only how useful it is. I don't know where in my code things are wrong - I only know, that when I insert figures, a huge space appears...

Comment: When I remove [H] it gets lot worse - even huger space and the figure on the next page and other figures before the figure, that should be number 1.

Comment: You should only use `[H]` if you really want the figure to stay exactly where you put it in your code. In other cases use a combination of `h`, `t`, `b` and `p`. If you use floating figures in all cases (no `H`),  then the order is not changed. The issue in your document arises from the use of non-floating figures with `\flushbottom` as others noted in the comments already. If you don't allow TeX to do its work don't wonder why it's not doing its work.

Comment: There are a lot of links in the answers to the MWE question. Several of them references How-Tos. Speculation: The reasons for odd reordering of figures are more `[H]` and is already explained in the answers to the link above. But if you do not want floats, see the link in the topmost comment. Nevertheless, I would really recommend to allow floating.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does latex stretch small sections across the whole page vertically?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10743/why-does-latex-stretch-small-sections-across-the-whole-page-vertically)

Comment: Basically, a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) is something that anyone could copy and paste into their own editor that would demonstrate your issues on compile, but without any other errors (unless they are part of your particular problem).  You should begin with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` so we know the entire setup and can reproduce it.  Help us help you.