# too-large vertical space due to twoside

Tags: vertical-alignment, double-sided

Thanks for your patience, as usual.

I have pinpointed a problem caused by the twoside argument for an article.

I have a minipage in a later part of a document.  When content in that minipage becomes large enough, it is moved to next page, creating an empty space on bottom of page before. When that happens, the items in the itemized list on page before are stretched to triple spacing.

I am pretty sure this problem is caused by twoside because I've cut out every thing else, one by one, and the funny line stretching does not happen if I remove twoside.

I want to keep the items with correct spacing; i.e., I need to just leave the white space on the bottom of page before minipage, no matter how large.  I cannot fix this with \newpage or such, there is no way to predict ahead of time how much space there might be or how much content will be in the minipage. It appears in about 95% of cases, the minipage does not flow onto next page.

My picture of the very wide spaced items on bottom of page before minipage:

[image]

The MRE is below.

The reason I am using twoside is that the report is required to use an even number of pages in the file. If report is even pages, then we insert a blank on 4th page.  That is necessary because there will be several other PDF reports and it is necessary for each one to begin on front side of paper. If it is not necessary to use twoside, you can tell me other way?

```
\documentclass[twoside,english,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
Paul Johnson

This loads the twoside argument for the article package. 

The bad side effect is if there is a minipage and it positions on
page 2, then the items on the page before are stretched to fill the
page. This does not happen if the twoside argument is removed.

I would like to know how to prevent this bad result. I prefer just
items with usual spacing and whitespace at bottom.

Words words words.

This is a paper

Here is a thing:
\begin{itemize}
\item item
\item item 2
\item item 3
\end{itemize}
Here is another thing:
\begin{itemize}
\item item
\item item 2 
\item item 3
\item item 4
\item item 5
\end{itemize}
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{1\columnwidth}%
I am a minipage.

As you add more and more stuff here, it eventually forces it to page
2, breaking line spacing on page 1. 

As you add more and more stuff here, it eventually forces it to page
2, breaking line spacing on page 1. 

As you add more and more stuff here, it eventually forces it to page
2, breaking line spacing on page 1. 

As you add more and more stuff here, it eventually forces it to page
2, breaking line spacing on page 1. 

As you add more and more stuff here, it eventually forces it to page
2, breaking line spacing on page 1. 

As you add more and more stuff here, it eventually forces it to page
2, breaking line spacing on page 1. 

As you add more and more stuff here, it eventually forces it to page
2, breaking line spacing on page 1. 

As you add more and more stuff here, it eventually forces it to page
2, breaking line spacing on page 1. 

As you add more and more stuff here, it eventually forces it to page
2, breaking line spacing on page 1. 

As you add more and more stuff here, it eventually forces it to page
2, breaking line spacing on page 1. 

As you add more and more stuff here, it eventually forces it to page
2, breaking line spacing on page 1. 

As you add more and more stuff here, it eventually forces it to page
2, breaking line spacing on page 1. 

As you add more and more stuff here, it eventually forces it to page
2, breaking line spacing on page 1. 

As you add more and more stuff here, it eventually forces it to page
2, breaking line spacing on page 1. 

As you add more and more stuff here, it eventually forces it to page
2, breaking line spacing on page 1. 

As you add more and more stuff here, it eventually forces it to page
2, breaking line spacing on page 1. 

As you add more and more stuff here, it eventually forces it to page
2, breaking line spacing on page 1. 

As you add more and more stuff here, it eventually forces it to page
2, breaking line spacing on page 1. 

As you add more and more stuff here, it eventually forces it to page
2, breaking line spacing on page 1. 

As you add more and more stuff here, it eventually forces it to page
2, breaking line spacing on page 1. 

As you add more and more stuff here, it eventually forces it to page
2, breaking line spacing on page 1. 

As you add more and more stuff here, it eventually forces it to page
2, breaking line spacing on page 1. %
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10743/why-does-latex-stretch-small-sections-across-the-whole-page-vertically

Comment: I am grateful for the guidance. My question has  the full MRE. Seems like it should be the one we refer to, not the other.  But, mostly, I'm happy to learn the magic word is "raggedbottom"!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the option `twoside` the article option also sets `\flushbottom` to make all pages the same height. To prevent this, you have to add `\raggedbottom` in the preamble.