# Default vertical page alignment for documents

Tags: vertical-alignment, double-sided

I notice that when I change

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, openright]{report}
```

to

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, openright, twoside]{report}
```

the vertical page alignment shifts to "center", while before it seemed it was "top".

[image]
[image]

Why is that? Is there anywhere I can declare default vertical alignment to be "top" for the whole document. I prefer not using extra/special packages.

Comment: Try `\raggedbottom` in the preamble.

Comment: @Jürgen, thanks. That `\raggedbottom` showed me the way to this post which answers the "why": https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10747/31153. I am not sure whether to delete or leave this question since it is a duplicate.