# Section caption and figure gap problem!

Tags: captions, gap

I have following codes:

```
\begin{document}
\appendix
\input{appendix1/appendix1.tex}
\input{appendix2/appendix2.tex}
\end{document}
```

And appendix 2 includes following codes:

```
\chapter{APPENDIX B }
\label{chp:appendixB}
\section{Grouped Test Images with Their Histograms}
\subsection*{Portrait}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{subfigure}[h!]{\textwidth}
  %\includegraphics[width=10cm, height=4.5cm]{einstein_image&histogram.jpg}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{einstein_image&histogram.jpg}
  \centering
  \caption{Einstein Image and Histogram}
  \label{fig:3_9_1}
  \caption*{Source: Courtesy of Gonzales \& Woods \cite{data_e} }
  \end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[h!]{\textwidth}
 \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{lena_image&histogram.jpg}
  \centering
 \caption{Lena Image and Histogram}
  \label{fig:3_9_2}
       \caption*{Source: Image Databases, Standard Test Images \cite{data_lwpcmphlwj}}
 \end{subfigure}
 \caption{Images and Histograms belong to Portrait Class}
 \end{figure}
```

I am attaching the results:

[image]
[image]

Why there is a duplication on the "Appendix B"?
Why there is a big gap between the captions?

Thanks,

Comment: If I were to make a wild guess, I'd suggest the extra space comes from using a documentclass that has `\flushbottom` (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10743), but I could well be wrong. Your first question is impossible to answer as it stands I think, as you haven't told us anything about the document class or other things in the preamble that might influence this. Can you make a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228) and add that to your question instead of the two snippets?