# Inserting images in LaTeX spacing problem

Tags: graphics

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,polynom,amssymb,venndiagram,mathtools,graphicx,fancyhdr,wrapfig}
\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}
\graphicspath{ {./spm/} }
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
.
.
.
.
\begin{enumerate}

    \setcounter{equation}{0}
    \item [(a)] 
    \begin{align}
    y-x&=7 \\
    y-x^2&=1
    \end{align}
    (1)-(2):
    \begin{align*}
    x^2-x-6&=0 \\
    (x-3)(x+2)&=0 \\
    x=3 \  \  \text{or} \ \  x=-2
        \end{align*}

    Substituting    $x=3$ and $x=-2$ into (1) , we get $y=10$ and $y=5$ respectively.
    $\therefore$ The points of intersection between the lines $y-x=7$ and $y-x^2=1$ are \\ \ (3 , 10) and (-2 , 5).
    \item[(b)]

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{geogebra-export}
    \item[(c)] 
    The height that the crossbar in Figure A must be raised 5 feet higher to achieve the position in Figure B. The coordinates of the ends of the rope are (-3,10) and (3,10).

\end{enumerate}
.
.
..
.
.
.
.
.
```

[image]

The spaces between the lines are abnormally large......it wasnt like this before i inserted the picture    may i know whats the problem?

Comment: p.s.  sorry about the tex code and words i know its a bit messy whoops

Comment: The following might be of interest to you: [Why does latex stretch small sections across the whole page vertically?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10743/134144). Using `\raggedbottom` might help in your case. However, this will lead to a large white space on the page before the image.

Comment: In order to format the code in your question, you can make use of te `{}` button as described here: [How do I mark code blocks?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192)

Comment: @LeeLaindingold The figure is too big to fit on page 6, so it is moved to the next page and LaTeX fills the previous page until the bottom line is at the bottom margin, because so requested by the `book` class. If you don't want to let the big figure float, add `\newpage` before the relevant `\item` command.