# Making a tikzpicture a figure sends it to next page

Tags: floats, page-breaking

I made a pie chart in my document. When it's not in a figure, everything is fine, the tikzpicture is between the two paragraphs I want. When I make it a figure, it goes to next page:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[nodes = {font=\sffamily}]
        \foreach \percent/\name in {
            81.5/Données reprises,
            18.5/Nouvelles données
            } {
            \ifx\percent\empty\else               % If \percent is empty, do nothing
                \global\advance\cyclecount by 1     % Advance cyclecount
                \global\advance\ind by 1            % Advance list index
                \ifnum3<\cyclecount                 % If cyclecount is larger than list
                \global\cyclecount=0              %   reset cyclecount and
                \global\ind=0                     %   reset list index
                \fi
                \pgfmathparse{\cyclelist[\the\ind]} % Get color from cycle list
                \edef\color{\pgfmathresult}         %   and store as \color
                % Draw angle and set labels
                \draw[fill={\color!50},draw={\color}] (0,0) -- (\angle:\radius)
                arc (\angle:\angle+\percent*3.6:\radius) -- cycle;
                \node at (\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:0.7*\radius) {\percent\,\%};
                \node[pin=\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:\name]
                at (\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:\radius) {};
                \pgfmathparse{\angle+\percent*3.6}  % Advance angle
                \xdef\angle{\pgfmathresult}         %   and store in \angle
            \fi
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
 \caption{Taux de propreté de la donnée}
 \label{Taux de propreté de la donnée}
\end{figure}
```

Is there a way to solve this?
Before posting, I checked the other questions, the solution mentionning the "float" is not acceptable for me because I don't want the space between paragraphs to change along the document.

Thanks :)

Comment: "Float" is the keyword. It is the float option itself which sends your figure to the next page.

Comment: So what do you recommend? I don't want my paragraph to have random space between them. I could make my figure smaller, but it's small enough for me.

Comment: (i) replace `center` environment with command `\centering` after `\begin{figure}`,   (ii) replace option `[!h] with `htb` , (iii) see if you can insert image earlier in text,  (iv) provide complete small document which reproduce your problem.

Comment: IIRC, [!h} is automatically translated as [htp].  As far as I can tell, the exclamation point does nothing useful, like hitting elevator buttons over and over.

Comment: Regarding non-floating floats: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text  Regarding space between paragraphs: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10743/why-does-latex-stretch-small-sections-across-the-whole-page-vertically/10747#10747