# vertical spacing of figures and paragraphs

Tags: spacing

I have a problem with the vertical spacing of my document. LaTeX adds an equal vertical space between all the figures, tables and paragraphs on a page. In result the last text or figure is placed at the bottom of the page and there is much white space on the page. I found out that the `\newpage` command helps, but I dont want to insert a `\newpage` at every page in the document...
update: here is some code and a picture of the output

```
\section{Einleitung}
\subsection{Ziel des Versuchs}

some text

\subsection{Versuchsstand}

Beim Versuch stand eine Synchronmaschine als Testobjekt mit folgenden Bemessungsdaten zur Verfügung\\

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Ankerspannung&$U_N=\SI{400}{\volt}$\\
Ankerstrom&$I_N=\SI{7.3}{\ampere}$\\
Scheinleistung&$S_N=\SI{5}{\kilo\volt\ampere}$\\
Erregerstrom&$I_{fdN}=\SI{2.4}{\ampere}$\\
Drehzahl&$n_N=\SI{1500}{\minute^{-1}}$\\
Leistungsfaktor&$\cos\varphi_N=\num{0.95}$\\
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Daten der Versuchsmaschine}
\end{center}
\label{tab:sm_daten}

Grundsätzlich kann für eine Synchronmaschine folgendes einphasiges Ersatzschaltbild genutzt werden.

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
\draw (-1,0) to [current direction={info={$\underline{I}_1$}}] (0,0) to [resistor={info={$R_1$}}] (2,0) to [inductor={info={$L_{1 \sigma}$}}] (4,0) to (5,0) to [inductor={info={$L_h$}}] (7,0) to [voltage source={direction info={info=$\underline{U}_p$}}    ] (7,-2) to (-1,-2);
\node [ocirc] at (-1,0) {};
\node [ocirc] at (-1,-2) {};
\node [contact] at (4.5,0) {};
\node [contact] at (4.5,-2) {};
\draw [->] (-1,-0.25) -- (-1,-1.75) node[midway, left] {$\underline{U}_1$};
\draw [->] (5.5,-0.25) -- (6.5,-0.25) node[midway, below] {$\underline{U}_a$};
\draw [->] (4.5,-0.25) -- (4.5,-1.75) node[midway, right] {$\underline{U}_h$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Einphasiges Ersatzschaltbild einer Synchronmaschine}
\label{fig:esb}
\end{figure}

Am Versuchsstand war die Versuchsmaschine über den in \textit{Abbildung \ref{fig:stromlaufplan}} dargestellten Stromlaufplan angeschlossen.

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[angle=90, width=\textwidth]{Inhalt/versuchsstand.jpg}
\caption{Stromlaufplan des Versuchsstandes}
\label{fig:stromlaufplan}
\end{figure}
```

[image: output of the code]

Comment: Welcome. Can you provide a MWE? A short version of what you already have? So we can see what you use and want to do.

Comment: the whole point of the floating figure and table mechanism is to allow latex to adjust the position of figures to avoid bad white space at a page break. So your problem description is hard to understand with no example code and it's impossible to suggest what you should change.

Comment: I added some code. Hope it's the right part.

Comment: It would be better to have provided a complete small document so people could run it, but note you are using `[H]` this _by design_ chooses to give bad spacing as it prevents the figures from moving so disables the entire latex float mechanism.

Comment: looking at the image it would seem that you are also using `\flushbottom` (or a class such as `book` that defaults to that). As you have disabled floats but specified that the last line of each page should be at the bottom of the page, tex has to stretch any white space on the page to meet the constraints you have set.

Comment: probably a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10743/why-does-latex-stretch-small-sections-across-the-whole-page-vertically

Comment: yeah you've been right. I had the option `twoside` in the document.
Didn't found this post, thanks for helping.

Comment: Related:  [Why should the H option not be used in floats?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370627/why-should-the-h-option-not-be-used-in-floats)