# Prevent automatic vertical space

Tags: vertical-spacing

I am writing a thesis with pdflatex and sometimes I can see that latex put extra vertical space (looks like `\vfill`) between some blocks (eg. paragraphs, images, formulas, sections). This is because latex cannot start a text from the next page at the current page (usually because of new section). See the attached page example.

I am fine with that but isn't there a way how to force latex to put the space at the end of the page rather than between 2 blocks? I think it would look much better than too big vertical space before some subsubsection...

[image]

Comment: Try adding in your preamble the directive `\raggedbottom` (the default is `\flushbottom`).

Comment: Thank you! This really looks like proper solution :) But I cannot mark your answer as a solution as it is only a direct answer or whatever (not really sure how it works there).

Comment: That's quite unimportant. Anyway, I'm sure there already exists such an answer.

Comment: [Why does latex stretch small sections across the whole page vertically?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10743/134144) could be a duplicate.