# Avoid uncessary spaces in Latex

Tags: floats

I am writing an article for the first time with Latex, I am using Overleaf as an online editor. I want to avoid unecessary spaces in my article which are the result of figures and adjustment. For example:

[image]

We can see how there are many vertical space between the figure and the text, for the next page is the output also in this way:

[image]

***Solution that I've tried:***

- Reduce the size of the image: not optimal because it won't be
  readable
- Change the float position of the figure from [H] to [h]: it didn't
  fix the problem, spaces still persist
  The code used for the first figure and text is :

```
    \begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{center}
    \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0pt}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{images/comparison2.png}
    \centering
    \caption{ORKG Interface for comparison between contribution}
    \vspace{-1.5em}
    \label{fig18}
    \end{center}
    \end{figure}

    \noindent{ORKG allows users to specify the structure of type's composition to describe research contributions. Templates are used to facilitate the organization of data by adding, editing or deleting attributes and their allocated information. For example, \autoref{fig19} highlights the specification of the features of describing a dataset:}
```

Comment: Using [H] is explicitly asking for bad spacing. Remove it completly and let the figures float. And replace the center environment by the \centering command, center adds additional space.

Comment: Isn't this the result of default spacing in latex documents that tries to use the entire available vertical space? Have you tried adding `\raggedbottom`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks for the answer, ok I will try removing the [H], but why I have to use the \centering ?

Comment: @MarkusG. thanks for the answer, no I didn't use \raggedbottom, can you explain more please ? where exactly I have to put it ? and why ?

Comment: Well, as you can see, latex tries to stretch out the content of a page to the entire available vertical space. This may or not be a desired effect that is caused by the `\flushbottom` option, if I'm not mistaken. It is the default for a few classes and as in your case can cause weirdly empty pages. Using `\raggedbottom` the space reserved for the lines is fixed and all pages filled from top to bottom. Which of these you want depends heavily on the use-case. Typically I put `\raggedbottom` in the line directly after the documentclass.

Comment: TeX tries to "float" the figures where it thinks is best.  If you have multiple large figures close together, it can run into problems because it doesn't have any material to put in those vertical spaces.  `\raggedbottom` tells TeX to move everything up, so that the vertical space is below the images and text.  What material is coming after the image?  What outcome are you wanting?

Comment: you are using `[H]` which is a request to get bad spacing (to fix manually) rather than let latex avoid bad spaces.

Comment: @MarkusG. it is mainly the result of H which _by design_ gives bad spacing,.

Comment: @all thanks for the support, so if I understood correctly, I have now to delete [H]  and use \raggedbottom ?

Comment: you should only use `\raggedbottom` if you want the baselines not to be the same on all pages. It is like using `\raggedright` rather than the default justified right margin, but in the vertical direction. Unrelated but you should not need `\noindent` here and never need `{...}` after `\noindent`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ok I will try that thx ! but shall I keep the [H] ?

Comment: No, get rid of all instances of `[H]`.

Comment: H disables all attempts by latex to give good spacing and lets you take full manual control, but then you have to move the figures by hand in the source and/or write more words to get better spacing. It is sometimes necessary as a last resort but only  if you really want to disable all latex's features and take full control.

Comment: Just look at the image you have posted. You can not get Figure 5.8, the ORKG paragraph and figure 5.9 on the same page. The reason latex has `figure` is to specify that the content may be moved to help with page breaking so if you use no option or use `[htbp]` then the figures will be re-inserted at a better place. `[H]` disables that so you force latex to give the output you show.

Comment: Ok Thank you @DavidCarlisle for your big help, if you want, you can put it as answer so I can accept as a solution for future users, thanks :)

Comment: oh it's a duplicate:-)

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables for centering or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text for discussion of H and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10743/why-does-latex-stretch-small-sections-across-the-whole-page-vertically/10747#10747  for vertically stretching

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ah ok, sorry I didn't see that, although I searched ti moch before I post this question !