# How do you adjust the distance between lists and text?

Tags: spacing

As you can see in the image below, there is too much gap between paragraphs and lists. It is also true for equations that are centered in a line and for the distance between a level 1 list element and a level 2 list element. How do I adjust this spacing? I am looking for a global solution, using `\vspace` for each one is a daunting task that also messes up spacing further.
[image]

[List of packages employed can be found here.](http://ix.io/2W63)
In this particular case, there is no point in sharing the document as it is just a simple list with no modifications.
Removing `\doublespacing` results in saner gaps but I need double spacing. Is there a way to add double spacing so that it does not affect the gap?

[.tex File](https://0x0.st/-A-L.tex)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please don't show just a screenshot, but also the underlying LaTeX code, ideally in the form of a compilable minimal working example that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`. Please also state whether you employ a LaTeX package, such as `enumitem` or `enumerate`, that simplifies making modifications to the appearance of enumerated and itemized lists.

Comment: @Mico Thank you. Unfortunately, the document is too large for me to share it, though I can write out the problematic part along with the packages employed.

Comment: the packages are not likely to be relevant, presumably you are using `\flushbottom` and have placed a non floating, not breakable object at the top of the following page so tex has to stretch the page you show.  You could use `\flushbottom` to allow the page to be short, or correct the unbreakable object that is forcing a bad page break.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have no flushes or floatbarriers, yet it's still the way it is.

Comment: I did not suggest you had any "flush" oir float barrier. I suggested you had a non floating display on the next page. It is the way it is due to code in your document that you hjave not shown, probably a large table on the next page.  If you want help you need to make a small two page document that shows the problem. It is impossible o debug why latex made a page break at that point with the information you have provided.  I suggested that you _add_ `\flushbottom` to your preamble so that excess space is added at the bottom of the page not between paragraphs.

Comment: Your question is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10743/why-does-latex-stretch-small-sections-across-the-whole-page-vertically  if you provide an example a specific answer could be provided, or if the answers there are sufficient we  coul dclose thos as duplicate.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Just as you suggested, I managed to separate the part of the document where I had issues with. As a beginner, I was afraid that I wouldn't be able to separate it but after doing it once, it's apparently easy and should be much more useful than me describing the issue. I updated the original question.

Comment: Please note that we generally do not like going to external pages for resources like tex file. Links tend to rot over time and thus your question will not be useful for others.

Comment: @daleif How do you share your tex documents instead? Do you use a code block? I am worried that it is going to get scraped and I will be punished for plagiarising my own work.

Comment: A bit of advise: Only load packages once. With very few exceptions, `hyperref` should be the last package to be loaded. If you are a beginnger, don't mess with `\parindent` and `\parskip`, they are there for a reason and then you don't need `\vspace` all over the place. Additionally **none** of you ``\\`` has any use here. If you ever feel the need to use ``\\`` in the text, then you're doing something wrong.

Comment: That if why we ask you to provide a minimal example, not your actual assignment.

Comment: @daleif I am using Org-Mode to write my document, strangely it loads the packages twice although I am sure each package has been mentioned once in the .org file. `parindent` is used because I find the default indentation too small. Though, I don't know how `\parskip` can make a differenc here but it moves a large table next page, leaving a page almost fully blank. As for `vspace`, it is necessary because LaTeX moves the title down otherwise.

Comment: Removing '\\'s (which are also added by Org-Mode for some reason, I need to pay emacs.stackexchange a visit) did help with the gaps.