# Spacing issue between section/subsection/paragraph etc

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, paragraphs

****Update**

This might be a repetitive question, but I do not know to prevent this additional white space from showing up.

Attached is my MWE to show additional white space that I have been unable to get rid of.  Specifically, page 11 in between the paragraphs and subsections.  I need to specify the strict spacing between all sections/subsections/paragraphs etc.

Here is my `MastersDoctoralThesis.cls` file:

```latex
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{MastersDoctoralThesis}[12/7/20 MastersDoctoralThesis]

\DeclareOption{11pt}{
    \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article} % book report
}

\ExecuteOptions{11pt}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass[11pt,letterpaper]{report}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5} 

\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}

\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\let\bvec\mathbf 
\RequirePackage{empheq}
\RequirePackage{amsbsy}
\RequirePackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\norm}[1]{\lVert}{\rVert}{#1}

\RequirePackage{mathpazo}

\newlength{\UOneInChapterSpace}
\newlength{\UHeadSpace}
\newlength{\UDoubleSpace}
\makeatletter

\RequirePackage{calc}
\setlength{\UOneInChapterSpace}{-40pt + 1in} 
\setlength{\UHeadSpace}{3ex}
\setlength{\UDoubleSpace}{1ex}

\RequirePackage{setspace}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{\addvspace{\UHeadSpace}}
\AtEndEnvironment{figure}{\addvspace{\UHeadSpace}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\addvspace{\UHeadSpace}}
\AtEndEnvironment{table}{\addvspace{\UHeadSpace}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{equation}{\addvspace{\UHeadSpace}}
\AtEndEnvironment{equation}{\addvspace{\UHeadSpace}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\singlespacing}

\RequirePackage{subfiles}

\RequirePackage{lipsum}

\RequirePackage{longtable} 
\RequirePackage{booktabs}

\newbool{graphicDraft}
\DeclareOption{graphicFinal}{\boolfalse{graphicDraft}}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{\baseclass}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\ifbool{graphicDraft}
    {\RequirePackage[draft]{graphicx}}
    {\RequirePackage[final]{graphicx}}

\RequirePackage{subcaption}
\RequirePackage{animate}
\RequirePackage{pdfpages}

\RequirePackage[font=singlespacing]{caption}

\RequirePackage{todonotes}

\RequirePackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    paper          = letterpaper,
    inner          = 1.25in,
    outer          = 1.25in,
    bindingoffset  = 0in,
    top            = 1in,
    bottom         = 1in,
    %head           = 2in,
    %showframe,
}

\RequirePackage{xcolor} % Required for specifying custom colors
\definecolor{BLACK}{HTML}{000000}
\definecolor{URED}{HTML}{CC0000}
\definecolor{midnightBlue}{HTML}{145680} % midnight blue
\definecolor{darkBrown}{HTML}{654321} % Dark brown
\definecolor{arsenic}{HTML}{3B444B}
\definecolor{darkGreen}{HTML}{00b300} % Dark green
\definecolor{tab:blue}{HTML}{1f77b4} % python

\RequirePackage{sectsty}

\chapternumberfont{\normalsize} 
\chaptertitlefont{\normalsize}

\RequirePackage[nostruts,compact]{titlesec}

\titlespacing{\chapter}{0in}{\UOneInChapterSpace}{\UHeadSpace}[0in] 
\titlespacing{\section}{0in}{0in}{\UDoubleSpace}[0in]
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0in}{0in}{\UDoubleSpace}[0in]
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0in}{0in}{\UDoubleSpace}[0in]
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{1em}{1ex}{1ex}[1em]

\titleformat{\chapter}
    [display]
    {\color{URED}\centering\normalfont\Large\bfseries\doublespacing}
    {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \Large\thechapter}
    {0in}
    {\MakeUppercase}
    []

\titleformat{\section}
    [hang]
    {\centering\singlespacing\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
    {\thesection}
    {1ex}
    {}
    []

\titleformat{\subsection}
    [hang]
    {\centering\singlespacing\normalfont\large\bfseries}
    {\thesubsection}
    {1ex}
    {}
    []

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
    [hang]
    {\centering\singlespacing\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
    {\thesubsubsection}
    {1ex}
    {}
    []

\titleformat{\paragraph}
    [runin]
    {\centering\singlespacing\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
    {\theparagraph}
    {1ex}
    {}
    []

\titleformat{\subparagraph}
    [runin]
    {\centering\singlespacing\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
    {\thesubparagraph}
    {1ex}
    {}
    []

\parskip=0pt

\RequirePackage[final]{microtype}  


\RequirePackage[defernums=true,
                hyperref,
                backref,
                backend=biber,
                style=ieee,
                natbib=true,
                refsegment=chapter,
                block=space
                ]{biblatex}

\setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep}

\defbibheading{references}[References]{% 
    \section{#1}
    \markboth{#1}{#1}%
    \singlespacing
}

\def\finalBibliography{
    {\singlespacing
    \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title={\uppercase{Bibliography}}] % Whole
    }
}

\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},
    bookmarksopen=true,
    bookmarksopenlevel=0,
    hypertexnames=true,
    colorlinks=true,
    citecolor=darkBrown,
    linktoc=all,
    linkcolor=URED,
    urlcolor=midnightBlue,
    pdfstartview={FitV},
    unicode,
    breaklinks=true,
}
\RequirePackage{doi}
\RequirePackage{url}

\RequirePackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\crefname{paragraph}{Paragraph}{Paragraphs}
\crefname{subparagraph}{Sub Paragraph}{Sub Paragraphs}

\captionsetup[sub]{labelsep=none, subrefformat=parens}

\RequirePackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\color{URED}\hfill \Large CONTENTS \hfill}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\color{URED}\hfill \Large LIST OF FIGURES \hfill}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\color{URED}\hfill \Large LIST OF TABLES \hfill}

\setlength{\cftsecindent}{1em}
\setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{2em}
\setlength{\cftsubsubsecindent}{3em}
\setlength{\cftparaindent}{4em}
\setlength{\cftsubparaindent}{5em}

\RequirePackage{xfp}
\RequirePackage{xparse}

\renewcommand\cftchapdotsep{2}
\renewcommand\cftsecdotsep{2}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecdotsep{2}
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsecdotsep{2}
\renewcommand\cftparadotsep{2}
\renewcommand\cftsubparadotsep{2}

\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vskip2pt}
\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vskip2pt}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecafterpnum{\vskip2pt}

\setlength{\cfttabindent}{0em}
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0em}

\RequirePackage{algpseudocode}
\RequirePackage{algorithm}

\def\thesistype#1{\gdef\@thesistype{#1}}
\def\degreeAchieved#1{\gdef\@degreeAchieved{#1}}
\def\department#1{\gdef\@department{#1}}
\def\departmentLink#1{\gdef\@departmentLink{#1}}
\def\submitdate#1{\gdef\@submitdate{#1}}
\newcommand\skiplines[1]{\vspace{#1\baselineskip}}

\newcommand\thesisTitle{
    {
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
        \vspace{1in}
        \centering
        \begin{spacing}{2}
            {\doublespacing\Large\bfseries\MakeUppercase{\@title}}\\
        \end{spacing}
        \large
        \skiplines{4}
        \begin{spacing}{2}
            by \\
            \@author \\
        \end{spacing}
        \skiplines{4}
        A \@thesistype ~submitted to the faculty of\\
        University\\
        in partial fulfillment of the requirements for the degree of \\
        \skiplines{4}
        {\@degreeAchieved}\\
        \skiplines{4}
        \begin{spacing}{2}
            \href{\@departmentLink}{\@department}\\
            \href{http://google.com}{University}\\
            \@submitdate
        \end{spacing}
    \end{minipage}
    \clearpage
    }
}


\def\copyrightyear#1{\gdef\@copyrightyear{#1}}

\newcommand\copyrightpage{
    {\newpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \topskip0pt
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}%
        \centering
        Copyright \copyright\ \@author\ \@copyrightyear \\
        \skiplines{1} % university requirement
        All Rights Reserved
    \end{minipage}%
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \newpage
    }
}

\def\committeeChair#1{\gdef\@committeeChair{#1}}
\def\advisorTitle#1{\gdef\@\advisorTitle{#1}}
\def\committeeMemberII#1{\gdef\@committeeMemberII{#1}}
\def\committeeMemberIII#1{\gdef\@committeeMemberIII{#1}}
\def\committeeMemberIIII#1{\gdef\@committeeMemberIIII{#1}}
\def\committeeMemberIIIII#1{\gdef\@committeeMemberIIIII{#1}}

\def\graduateDean#1{\gdef\@graduateDean{#1}}
\def\departmentChair#1{\gdef\@departmentChair{#1}}
\def\departmentChairTitle#1{\gdef\@departmentChairTitle{#1}}
\def\deptmentCollegeSchool#1{\gdef\@deptmentCollegeSchool{#1}}

\def\approvaldepartment#1{\gdef\@approvaldepartment{#1}}
\def\chairDateApproved#1{\gdef\@chairDateApproved{#1}}
\def\committeeMemberIIDateApproved#1{\gdef\@committeeMemberIIDateApproved{#1}}
\def\committeeMemberIIIDateApproved#1{\gdef\@committeeMemberIIIDateApproved{#1}}
\def\committeeMemberIIIIDateApproved#1{\gdef\@committeeMemberIIIIDateApproved{#1}}
\def\committeeMemberIIIIIDateApproved#1{\gdef\@committeeMemberIIIIIDateApproved{#1}}

\def\bfunderline#1{\underline{\kern 1in \textbf{#1}\kern 1in}}

\RequirePackage{tabularx} % pagewidth tables
\RequirePackage{array} % Specify width of tables
\RequirePackage{ragged2e} % Allows for justification of sections

\long \def \dissertationapproval{%
    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \textbf{\Large University Graduate School} \\
        \skiplines{2}
        \textbf{\Large STATEMENT OF DISSERTATION APPROVAL}
        \skiplines{2}
        %
        \justify
        \begin{doublespace}
            The dissertation of\hspace{1in}\bfunderline{\@author} \\
            \skiplines{2}
            has been approved by the following supervisory committee members:

            \begin{table}[H] % [htbp]
                \centering    \begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.6\textwidth}p{0.1\textwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.2\textwidth}}
                    \bfseries{\@committeeChair} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{ , Chair} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries{\@chairDateApproved}} \\
                    \cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{3-3}          &       & \tiny{Date Approved} \\
                        &    &    \\ % add extra row between the committee members
                    \bfseries{\@committeeMemberII} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{ , Member} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries{\@committeeMemberIIDateApproved}} \\
                    \cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{3-3}          &       & \tiny{Date Approved} \\
                        &    &    \\ % add extra row between the committee members
                    \bfseries{\@committeeMemberIII} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{ , Member} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries{\@committeeMemberIIIDateApproved}} \\
                    \cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{3-3}          &       & \tiny{Date Approved} \\
                        &    &    \\ % add extra row between the committee members
                    \bfseries{\@committeeMemberIIII} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{ , Member} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries{\@committeeMemberIIIIDateApproved}} \\
                    \cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{3-3}          &       & \tiny{Date Approved} \\
                        &    &    \\ % add extra row between the committee members
                    \bfseries{\@committeeMemberIIIII} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{ , Member} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries{\@committeeMemberIIIIIDateApproved}} \\
                    \cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{3-3}          &       & \tiny{Date Approved} \\
                \end{tabular}%
            \end{table}%
            
            \justify
            and by \hspace{1in}\bfunderline{\@departmentChair}, {\@departmentChairTitle} of \\
            the {\@deptmentCollegeSchool} of \hspace{1in}\bfunderline{\@approvaldepartment} \\
            and by \bfunderline{\@graduateDean}, Dean of The Graduate School.\\
        \end{doublespace}
    \end{minipage}
    \vspace*{\fill}
}

\def\abstractString#1{\gdef\@abstractString{#1}}

\newcommand\abstractPage{
    {\newpage
    \chapter*{Abstract}
        % manually set to page iii (University requirement)
        \setcounter{page}{3}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\uppercase{Abstract}}
        \hspace{\parindent}
        \begin{doublespace}
            \@abstractString
        \end{doublespace}
    }
}


\def\dedication#1{\gdef\@dedication{#1}}

\newcommand\dedicationPage{
    {\newpage
        \clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}\addtocounter{page}{-1} 
        \topskip0pt
        \vspace*{\fill}
        \noindent
        \begin{minipage}[c]{.95\textwidth}%
            \centering
            \@dedication
        \end{minipage}%
        \vspace*{\fill}
    }
}

\def\frontispiece#1{\gdef\@frontispiece{#1}}

\newcommand\frontispiecePage{
    {\newpage        
        \clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}
        \topskip0pt
        \vspace*{\fill}
        \noindent
        \begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}%
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{{\@frontispiece}}
        \end{minipage}%
        \vspace*{\fill}
    }
}


\RequirePackage{epigraph}
\def\epigraphQuote#1{\gdef\@epigraphQuote{#1}}
\def\epigraphAuthor#1{\gdef\@epigraphAuthor{#1}}

\newcommand\epigraphPage{
    {\newpage
        \clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}
        \topskip0pt
        \vspace*{\fill}
        \noindent
        \begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}%
            \centering
            \epigraph{\Large{\@epigraphQuote}}{---{\@epigraphAuthor}}
        \end{minipage}%
        \vspace*{\fill}
    }
}


\def\Acknowledgement#1{\gdef\@Acknowledgement{#1}}

\newcommand\AcknowledgementPage{
    {
    \chapter*{Acknowledge}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\uppercase{Acknowledge}}
    \hspace{\parindent}
    \begin{doublespace}
        \@Acknowledgement
    \end{doublespace}
    }
}


\def\NotationAndSymbols#1{\gdef\@NotationAndSymbols{#1}}

\newcommand\NotationSymbolsPage{
    {
    \chapter*{Notation and Symbols}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\uppercase{Notation and Symbols}}
        \begin{center}
            \@NotationAndSymbols
        \end{center}
    }
}

\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}

\newcommand\frontMatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{roman}}

\newcommand\mainMatter{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{1em}\noindent{\bf\uppercase{Chapters}}\hfill\par} 
    \cleardoublepage
    
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{} 
    \lhead{} 
    \rhead{\thepage} 
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
    
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
      \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
      \fancyhf{} 
      %\fancyhead[R]{\thepage} 
    }
    
    \pagenumbering{arabic} 
    \doublespacing 
}

\newcommand\backMatter{%
    \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
    \else
    \clearpage
    \fi
    % \@mainmatterfalse
}

\renewcommand\cftfigafterpnum{\vskip5pt\par}
\renewcommand\cfttabafterpnum{\vskip5pt\par}

\newcommand\tableOfContents{
    {
    \hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}
    \clearpage
    \pdfbookmark{Table of Contents}{toc}
    \tableofcontents
    
    \clearpage
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\uppercase{List of Figures}}
    \listoffigures
    
    \clearpage
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\uppercase{List of Tables}}
    \listoftables
    }
}

\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\uppercase\relax} 

\RequirePackage{mwe}

\endinput
```

Here is my `StudentInfo.tex` file:

```latex
\author        {Full Name}
\title        {Thesis title}
\thesistype    {dissertation}
\degreeAchieved    {Doctor of Philosophy}
\department    {Department of xx}
\departmentLink    {}
\submitdate    {xx yyyy}
\copyrightyear  {\the\year{}}

\abstractString    {Abstract goes here.  \\\indent More info here.}

\dedication    {To Science!}

\frontispiece    {example-image-a} % 

\epigraphQuote    {``Quote"} 
\epigraphAuthor    {Famous Individual}

\Acknowledgement{Acknowledge \ldots \\\indent more recognition.}

\NotationAndSymbols{
\begin{tabular}{p{0.05\textwidth}p{0.9\textwidth}}
    \toprule
    x     & \emph{Var} - the variable x. \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
}

\approvaldepartment     {Dept.}

\graduateDean           {xx}
\departmentChair        {yy}
\departmentChairTitle   {Chair}
\deptmentCollegeSchool  {Department}

\committeeChair         {Advisor}
\advisorTitle           {Associate Professor, Associate Chair}

\committeeMemberII      {xx}
\committeeMemberIII     {yy}
\committeeMemberIIII    {zz}
\committeeMemberIIIII   {aa}

\chairDateApproved                  {xx xx \the\year{}}
\committeeMemberIIDateApproved      {xx xx \the\year{}}
\committeeMemberIIIDateApproved     {xx xx \the\year{}}
\committeeMemberIIIIDateApproved    {xx xx \the\year{}}
\committeeMemberIIIIIDateApproved   {xx xx \the\year{}}
```

Here is my `bibliography.bib` file

```latex
@article{test,
author = {Last, First},
doi = {xxxx},
issn = {xxx},
journal = {ABC},
number = {1-2},
pages = {12--22},
title = {{Title}},
volume = {111},
year = {xxxx}
}
```

Last but not least, here is the MWE that calls the cls and student info file

```latex
% The class file specifying the document structure
\documentclass{MastersDoctoralThesis}

\input{StudentInfo.tex}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
    \frontMatter
    \begin{center}
        \thesisTitle
        \copyrightpage
        \dissertationapproval
    \end{center}
    \abstractPage
    \dedicationPage
    \frontispiecePage
    \epigraphPage
    \tableOfContents
    \NotationSymbolsPage
    \AcknowledgementPage
    
    \mainMatter
    \chapter{\uppercase{Introduction}}\label{Chapter1}
        \section{Overview}
            \lipsum[1] \cite{test}
        
        \section{Background and significance}
            \lipsum[1-3]
        
        \section{Hypothesis and Rationale}\label{Hyptohesis_Rationale}
        \subsection{Aim 1}\label{aim:1}
            \lipsum[1]
        
        \subsection{Aim 2}\label{aim:2}
            \lipsum[2]
        
        \subsection{Aim 3}\label{aim:3}
            \lipsum[3]
        
        \section{Impact and Intellectual Contributions}\label{sec:impact}
            \lipsum[1-2]
    
        % Bibliography
        \printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment, heading=references]
        
    \chapter[\uppercase{Multiline title}]{\uppercase{Multiline \protect\\ title}}\label{Chapter2}
        
        \lipsum[1]
    
        \section{Abstract}
            \lipsum[1]
        
        \section{Introduction}
            \lipsum[1-5]
        
        \section{Section1}\label{sec:Section1}

        \subsection{Subsection1}\label{subsec:Subsection1}
            \lipsum[1-2]

            \begin{figure}[tbp]
                \centering
                \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                    \centering
                    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]
                    {example-image-a}
                    \subcaption{\label{fig:a}}
                \end{subfigure}%
                \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                    \centering
                    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]
                    {example-image-b}
                    \subcaption{\label{fig:b}}
                \end{subfigure}%
                \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                    \centering
                    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]
                    {example-image-c}
                    \subcaption{\label{fig:c}}
                \end{subfigure}%
                \caption{\subref{fig:a} \ldots \subref{fig:b} \ldots \subref{fig:c}
                \ldots}
                \label{fig:Figure_1}
            \end{figure}
            
            \lipsum[1-2]
        
        \subsection{Subsection2}\label{subsec:Subsection2}
            \lipsum[1-2]
            
            \begin{figure}[tbp]
                \centering
                \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.9\textwidth}
                    \centering
                    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]
                    {example-image-a}
                    \subcaption{\label{fig:d}}
                \end{subfigure} \\[1ex]
                \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
                    \centering
                    \includegraphics[height=5cm]
                    {example-image-b}
                    \subcaption{\label{fig:e}}
                \end{subfigure}%
                \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
                    \centering
                    \includegraphics[height=5cm]
                    {example-image-c}
                    \subcaption{\label{fig:f}}
                \end{subfigure}
                \caption{\ldots \subref{fig:d} \ldots \subref{fig:e} \ldots
                \subref{fig:f} \ldots}
                \label{fig:Figure_2}
            \end{figure}
        
        \subsection{SubSection3}\label{subsec:Subsection3}
            \lipsum[1-2]
        
        \paragraph{Paragraph1}\label{par:Paragraph1}
            \lipsum[6-7]
            
            \begin{figure}[tbp]
                \centering
                \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
                    \centering
                    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]
                    {example-image-a}
                    \subcaption{\label{fig:g}}
                \end{subfigure}%
                \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
                    \centering
                    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]
                    {example-image-b}
                    \subcaption{\label{fig:h}}
                \end{subfigure}%
                \caption{\ldots \subref{fig:g} \ldots
                \subref{fig:h} \ldots} 
                \label{fig:Figure_3}
            \end{figure}
            
        \paragraph{Paragraph2}\label{par:Paragraph2}
            \lipsum[8-10]
            
            \begin{figure}[tbp]
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]
                {example-image-a}
                \caption{\ldots} 
                \label{fig:Figure_4}
            \end{figure}
            
            \lipsum[66]
            
            \begin{figure}[tbp]
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]
                {example-image-16x10}
                \caption{\ldots} 
                \label{fig:Figure_5}
            \end{figure}
            
            \lipsum[75]
        
        \subsection{SubSection4}\label{subsec:Subsection4}
            \lipsum[10-12]
    \appendix
    \finalBibliography
\end{document}
```

On page #11 I was able to recreate the spacing issue.  I'm just not sure how to make the spacing between sections/subsections/paragraphs/subparagraphs all the same.  I did make spacing above and below figures/tables/algorithms the same.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: you haven't shown the relevant code but presumably you are using `\flushbottom` and have a large unbreakable object on the next page. You could use `\raggedbottom` and/or allow whatever is preventing a good page break to float.

Comment: duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10743/why-does-latex-stretch-small-sections-across-the-whole-page-vertically  most likely?

Comment: Let me know what keywords I should be looking for?  If need be I can include my entire cls file, I can.  Like you mentioned, I'm not sure how to keep page breaks specified and allow figures/tables to float to better locations.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by keywords. You should be able to make a small document that shows the issue but failing that show why the page is short, I assume you have something large on the next page that will not fit, latex normally floats figures so that does not occur. perhaps you have used `[H]`  to prevent that?  You can use `\raggedbottom` that still leaves the page with not enough text to fill the  page, but all the space goes at the bottom. (vertical analog of using `\raggedright` rather than justified text to keep even word spacing at the expense of uneven right margin)

Comment: I will work on creating a small document that shows this.

Comment: In general it is always good to include an example document but here, it's most likely a duplicate, unless you are saying `\raggedbottom` doesn't solve the issue. If the question will be closed as a duplicate anyway there isn't a lot of need to make a small example.

Comment: I'm not sure the best way to share an example.  It is a subfile project with nested subfolders.  I was able to recreate the issue using a skeleton example that had spacing issues between sections, subsections, and paragraphs.  Is it possible to share an example via GitLab?

Comment: You really should be able to make a single file example to post inline. Your question here is archived forever and links to gitlab or other external sites will break or point to different code. The page breaking is completely unaffected by any complications of subfiles etc so you do not need that on an example. But as I say your question sounds like an often asked question about the behaviour of `\flushbottom` and it may not need an example at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123835/discussion-between-christopher-creveling-and-david-carlisle).

Comment: The extra space is coming from the ``\addvspace` you inserted before a float (figures, tables) when the float goes to the top of the page. If you correct this it will no affect spaces before sections, subsection, etc.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

I used a simplified MWE from the one posted to illustrate the problem.

The additional space you are viewing is, in a sense, an artifact of this particular page because of the float.

The class sets all title spaces. Also inserts **before** and after the figure environment (also table and equation) a `3ex` space using `\addvspace`. When a float is pushed to the top of the page, this space is not added.

`3ex` is slightly larger than a baselineskip and this extra space is inserted before **Paragraph2**, who shows four lines in the page.

A  solution is to change in  `MastersDoctoralThesis.sty` `\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{\addvspace{\UHeadSpace}}` to `\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{}`

Wrong spacing before `\paragraph`

[image: w]

Using `\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{}` in  MastersDoctoralThesis.sty.

Now **Paragraph2**  shows five lines in the page.

[image: g]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex
\documentclass{MastersDoctoralThesis}

\usepackage{showframe} % show the margin

\begin{document}

\section{Section1}  
\subsection{Subsection1}
\lipsum[1-2]

\subsection{Subsection2}
\lipsum[1-2]    

\subsection{SubSection3}\label{subsec:Subsection3}
\lipsum[1]

\paragraph{Paragraph1}
1.  \lipsum[1-2]        

\setlength{\UHeadSpace}{0pt}  % add before \begin{figure} <<<<<<<<<
\begin{figure}[tbp]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]
        {example-image-a}
        \subcaption{\label{fig:g}}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]
        {example-image-b}
        \subcaption{\label{fig:h}}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \caption{\ldots \subref{fig:g} \ldots
    \subref{fig:h} \ldots} 
    \label{fig:Figure_3}
    \setlength{\UHeadSpace}{3ex} % add before \end{figure}  <<<<<<<<<<
\end{figure}

\paragraph{Paragraph2}
1.  \lipsum[1]
2   \lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Going back to the posted MWE, using `\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{}` the page #11 appears now with seven lines under **Paragraphs2** and no space anomalies.

[image: 11]

Comment: @Christopher Creveling Please see the updated answer.

Comment: I was able to update the figure spacing as you indicated in the udpated answer.  Would I still need to include the local change to each figure?  ```\setlength{\UHeadSpace}{0pt}  % add before \begin{figure} <<<<<<<<<``` as indicated in your answer?  Same with the after figure ```\setlength{\UHeadSpace}{3ex} % add before \end{figure}  <<<<<<<<<<```?

Comment: This might be a different question, but would this change also make the spacing between sections, subsections, subsubsections, and paragraphs the same?

Comment: @Christopher Creveling The extra space is coming from the ``\addvspace` you inserted before a float (figures, tables) when the float goes to the top of the page. If you correct this it will no affect spaces before sections, subsection, etc. Or if you prevent the float from "floating" .