# Using titlesec how can I prevent space from showing up between chapters and sections if I do not have text between them?

Tags: titlesec

I am stuck with a very strict requirement to keep the space between chapter/sections/subsections/paragraph headers the same.  After a chapter header, I need to have a triple space.  After section headers, I need to have a double space.  I have been able to do this, however, if I do not have additional text between a chapter title and the first section header, then the spaces add (triple space + double space).  Is there a way to have an if statement acknowledges that if there is text, only use a triple space, whereas if the text is displayed, then use the double space?

```
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0in}{\UOneInChapterSpace}{\UHeadSpace}[0in] 
\titlespacing{\section}{0in}{0in}{\UDoubleSpace}[0in]
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0in}{0in}{\UDoubleSpace}[0in]
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0in}{0in}{\UDoubleSpace}[0in]
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{1em}{1ex}{1ex}[1em]

\titleformat{\chapter}
    [display]
    {\color{URED}\centering\normalfont\Large\bfseries\doublespacing}
    {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \Large\thechapter}
    {0in}
    {\MakeUppercase}
    []

\titleformat{\section}
    [hang]
    {\centering\singlespacing\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
    {\thesection}
    {1ex}
    {}
    []

\titleformat{\subsection}
    [hang]
    {\centering\singlespacing\normalfont\large\bfseries}
    {\thesubsection}
    {1ex}
    {}
    []

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
    [hang]
    {\centering\singlespacing\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
    {\thesubsubsection}
    {1ex}
    {}
    []

\titleformat{\paragraph}
    [runin]
    {\centering\singlespacing\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
    {\theparagraph}
    {1ex}
    {}
    []

\titleformat{\subparagraph}
    [runin]
    {\centering\singlespacing\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
    {\thesubparagraph}
    {1ex}
    {}
    []
```

I posted a previous question that has the entire cls file ([Link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595624/spacing-issue-between-section-subsection-paragraph-etc?noredirect=1#comment1493949_595624)).  I'm just not sure how to do this.

Thank you!

Comment: Pleas see my answer to your previous question https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/597520/161015

Comment: Are you using  `\documentclass{MastersDoctoralThesis}` ?

Comment: Yes, I am using the class file mentioned in the link.  I was the one who wrote it but was just not sure how to address this spacing issue.

Comment: Ohh! I was preparing an answer for the preamble. Now I will see how to modify the class.

Comment: Thank you so much!  This was the first class file I have written so if there is any advice you have regarding it please let me know.  I've been scouring various StackOverflow comments the past year to get to where I am now.

Comment: Did my answer to your former question helped? It was a nice challenge to find where the extra space was coming from.

Comment: After reading through your answer that did make sense why the additional space was showing up.  I just haven't had a chance to implement it into my actual project.  There are over 50 figures so I wasn't sure if I needed to add the local fix to each image.

Comment: It is not needed. The problem is the addvspace in `\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{\addvspace{\UHeadSpace}}` and similars.

Comment: Please see the updated answer to your former question

Answer (score 1):

You might incorporate these setting to your class. The grid is set to `\baselineskip` at doublespace. No extra space appears after title and section if there is no text.

```
%%***************************************************** titlespacing starts
\newlength{\Beforesec}
\setlength{\Beforesec}{2ex}
\newlength{\Aftersec}
\setlength{\Aftersec}{1ex}

\setlength{\UOneInChapterSpace}{-45pt + 1in} 
\setlength{\UHeadSpace}{3\baselineskip}
\setlength{\UDoubleSpace}{2\baselineskip}   

\titlespacing{\chapter}{0in}{\UOneInChapterSpace}{\UHeadSpace+\Beforesec}[0in] 
\titlespacing{\section}{0in}{\Beforesec}{\UDoubleSpace+\Aftersec}[0in]
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0in}{0in}{0.5\UDoubleSpace}[0in]
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0in}{0in}{0.5\UDoubleSpace}[0in]
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{1em}{1ex}{1ex}[1em]
%%***************************************************** titlespacing ends
```

**Section after title** without text in between

[image: w]

**Text after title**

[image: z]

Test this code

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass{MastersDoctoralThesis}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{% GRID
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,
        help lines/.append style={line width=0.05pt,
            color=white},
        major divisions/.style={help lines,line width=0.5pt,
            color=blue!40} ]
        \draw[help lines] (current page.south west) grid[step=0.5pt]
        (current page.north east);
        \draw[major divisions] (current page.south west) grid[step=22pt] % baselineskip = 22pt at double space
        (current page.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}   

%%***************************************************** titlespacing starts
\newlength{\Beforesec}
\setlength{\Beforesec}{2ex}
\newlength{\Aftersec}
\setlength{\Aftersec}{1ex}

\setlength{\UOneInChapterSpace}{-45pt + 1in} 
\setlength{\UHeadSpace}{3\baselineskip}
\setlength{\UDoubleSpace}{2\baselineskip}   

\titlespacing{\chapter}{0in}{\UOneInChapterSpace}{\UHeadSpace+\Beforesec}[0in] 
\titlespacing{\section}{0in}{\Beforesec}{\UDoubleSpace+\Aftersec}[0in]
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0in}{0in}{0.5\UDoubleSpace}[0in]
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0in}{0in}{0.5\UDoubleSpace}[0in]
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{1em}{1ex}{1ex}[1em]
%%***************************************************** titlespacing ends

\begin{document}
\mainMatter %% sets\doublespacing 

\chapter[\uppercase{Multiline title}]{\uppercase{Multiline \protect \\  title}} 
1   \lipsum[1]
\section{Section1}
2   \lipsum[2]
\section{Section2}
\section{Section3}
\section{Section4}
3   \lipsum[3]
\subsection{Subsection1}
4   \lipsum[4]  
\subsection{Subsection2}    
\subsection{Subsection3}    
\subsection{Subsection4}
5   \lipsum[5]  
\paragraph{Paragraph1}
6   \lipsum[6]  
\paragraph{Paragraph2}
\paragraph{Paragraph3}
\paragraph{Paragraph4}
7   \lipsum[7]
\end{document
```

Comment: That is so close.  However, I'm still getting slightly more space between a chapter title and no text before a section header than a chapter title with text before the section header.  Using SumatraPDF it appears that there is an additional 0.9 in space before the section header when I set all spaces to 0\baselineskip.  Would you by chance know how to fix that?

Comment: @Christopher Creveling LaTeX does not typeset on a grid. There are al lot of glue space in that page to make nice paragraphs instead. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405237/161015