# Multiple breakable tcolorboxes produce additional space

Tags: tcolorbox, vertical-spacing

I am using `tcolorbox` with `breakable` option to state theorems and definitions. But when I list them, sometimes they don't break and passes to the next page. The problem is that the first page is left with vertical space not in the end of the page, in the middle of texts. For instance,

```
\documentclass[openany, 12pt]{extbook}
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{top = 1in, bottom = 1in, left = 1.5cm, right = 1.5cm}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{1 pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\newtcolorbox{thm}{breakable, colback = white, colframe = Red, boxrule = 0.5mm, sharpish corners, left = 0.5mm,right = 0.5mm, after skip = 2mm, before skip = 2mm,}
\newcommand{\Theorem}[2]{{\large\color{Red!90!white}\textsf{\textbf{Theorem #1}}}\tcblower #2}
\newcommand{\theorem}[2]{\begin{thm}\Theorem{#1}{#2}\end{thm}}

\begin{document}

\theorem{(Some Theorem)}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ex est, ullamcorper scelerisque pulvinar sed, tempor ut augue. Fusce non fermentum urna, vel rutrum sapien. Morbi faucibus libero enim, vel malesuada quam luctus sed. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam imperdiet nisl eu purus interdum, et aliquam ligula pulvinar. Nulla consectetur eros quis finibus aliquet. Phasellus vitae quam vel ipsum feugiat accumsan non eget arcu. Aenean feugiat erat nunc, sit amet lacinia velit pulvinar et. Quisque sodales massa at tincidunt efficitur. Fusce at convallis lacus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam eget orci id quam luctus facilisis. In rutrum quis leo a pretium. Nulla finibus aliquet fermentum. Phasellus elementum consequat mauris nec viverra. Aenean imperdiet mauris quis ligula dictum fringilla.

Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Curabitur varius metus turpis, quis auctor leo iaculis a. Vestibulum pellentesque, felis sit amet auctor varius, dolor urna hendrerit nulla, eget dignissim sem purus at libero. Nullam eget tellus non magna semper convallis vel eget neque. Cras ut hendrerit eros. Integer eu ante eget ante euismod tempor. Nulla ultricies elit sed lectus rutrum, eu venenatis diam mollis. Maecenas fringilla luctus arcu, non placerat magna.

Praesent sed lorem ut lectus hendrerit blandit. Nullam condimentum turpis a tortor facilisis hendrerit. Fusce interdum velit in turpis consequat, eu congue felis facilisis. Aliquam sit amet viverra orci. Nulla dapibus leo libero, ac accumsan massa vulputate vestibulum. Sed quis blandit nisl. Morbi metus lacus, consectetur id ante ut, molestie tincidunt elit. Fusce ut neque vel dui tincidunt consequat. Proin molestie interdum consectetur. Praesent et magna in dolor aliquet efficitur at quis lacus.}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ex est, ullamcorper scelerisque pulvinar sed, tempor ut augue. Fusce non fermentum urna, vel rutrum sapien. Morbi faucibus libero enim, vel malesuada quam luctus sed. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam imperdiet nisl eu purus interdum, et aliquam ligula pulvinar. Nulla consectetur eros quis finibus aliquet. Phasellus vitae quam vel ipsum feugiat accumsan non eget arcu. Aenean feugiat erat nunc, sit amet lacinia velit pulvinar et. Quisque sodales massa at tincidunt efficitur. Fusce at convallis lacus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam eget orci id quam luctus facilisis. In rutrum quis leo a pretium. Nulla finibus aliquet fermentum. Phasellus elementum consequat mauris nec viverra. Aenean imperdiet mauris quis ligula dictum fringilla.

\[\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s} = \prod_{p} \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}\]

Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Curabitur varius metus turpis, quis auctor leo iaculis a. Vestibulum pellentesque, felis sit amet auctor varius, dolor urna hendrerit nulla, eget dignissim sem purus at libero. Nullam eget tellus non magna semper convallis vel eget neque. Cras ut hendrerit eros. Integer eu ante eget ante euismod tempor. Nulla ultricies elit sed lectus rutrum, eu venenatis diam mollis. Maecenas fringilla luctus arcu, non placerat magna. Praesent sed lorem ut lectus hendrerit blandit. Nullam condimentum turpis a tortor facilisis hendrerit. Fusce interdum velit in turpis consequat, eu congue felis facilisis. Aliquam sit amet viverra orci. Nulla dapibus leo libero, ac accumsan massa vulputate vestibulum. Sed quis blandit nisl.

\theorem{(Some Theorem)}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ex est, ullamcorper scelerisque pulvinar sed, tempor ut augue. Fusce non fermentum urna, vel rutrum sapien. Morbi faucibus libero enim, vel malesuada quam luctus sed. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam imperdiet nisl eu purus interdum, et aliquam ligula pulvinar. Nulla consectetur eros quis finibus aliquet. Phasellus vitae quam vel ipsum feugiat accumsan non eget arcu. Aenean feugiat erat nunc, sit amet lacinia velit pulvinar et. Quisque sodales massa at tincidunt efficitur. Fusce at convallis lacus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam eget orci id quam luctus facilisis. In rutrum quis leo a pretium. Nulla finibus aliquet fermentum. Phasellus elementum consequat mauris nec viverra. Aenean imperdiet mauris quis ligula dictum fringilla.}

\end{document}
```

produces unusually large space between the texts and math like
[image]
[image]

How can I get rid of that or at least place the vertical space to the end of the page?

Comment: Adding `\raggedbottom` to the preamble of your document should help. See also: [Why does latex stretch small sections across the whole page vertically?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10743/134144)

Comment: Note that the title is relatively large and unbreakable.